# CSS & HTML: Divs aligning in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am trying to create a landing page here: http://www.serik.me and it looks good in Chrome & Safari but is not working in Firefox. Specifically, the #bottom ID is getting pushed up into the #righthalf ID.

When I tried to validate the CSS I ran into a bunch of errors with the embedded flash. I also tried all sorts of positioning fixes (absolute, relative, floats etc) but nothing seems to work.

Is it a problem with my  in the HTML?

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I want the three rounded tables at the bottom to be centered across the entire page below the content above it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's some crazy keytar shred man! Nice tunes :)

Comment: Haha thanks man! Better producer than hacker at this point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
.bottom {clear:both}
```

That should be all you need. Sorry I can't explain why it's working in Chrome and not Firefox, but this should at least get you on your way. (Tested in FF4)

The bottom isn't really centered, but it looks the same in Chrome as in FF with that fix.

I didn't see any major problems with your html, although it didn't validate for `alt` attributes and the embed stuff. Those shouldn't be affecting your layout though.

Good luck, the site looks nice.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly! I did some quick research as to why {clear:both} fixes the problem and I think I understand what happened, but not what it had to do with FF. In any case, awesome! Good looks! What would be the best way to center the .bottom in this scenario? The good old <center> worked for me, but the CSS auto margin left/right did not work. Any additional advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Serik: Looks like you already centered it! If this was helpful and resolved your problem, please consider accepting it as your answer by clicking the checkbox. It's a habit you'll want to get into if you decide to stick around ;) GL with the site and the jamz, my parting advice is this: Don't use tables for layout, use CSS.

Comment: Thanks again. As I get more and more comfortable with CSS I will definitely drop the tables